# Kendo stacked bar chart categories

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I got data in this Json format:

```
var demoData = [{
    Name: 'Category_1',
    Total: 100,
    Items: [{
        Name: 'Sub_Category_1_1',
        Total: 50
        }]
    },{
    Name: 'Category_2',
    Total: 20,
    Items: [{
        Name: 'Sub_Category_2_1',
        Total: 15
        },{
        Name: 'Sub_Category_2_2',
        Total: 45
    }]
}];
```

I use this data for kendo stacked bar chart, but first I parse to get a flat list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Items.length; j++) {
        dataArray.push({
            name: data[i].Items[j].Name,
            stack: data[i].Name,
            data: [data[i].Items[j].Total]
        });
    }
}
```

Everything works, however, I would like to display category name under bars. But when I add

```
categoryAxis: {
    categories: catNames
}
```

where `cats` is array `['Category_1', 'Category_2', ....]`, it happens that all rendered bars get category named "Category_1" and "Category_2" and etc. have no bars above.

How should I configure kendo chart to display category names underneaths properly?

I have tried feeding data to`dataSource` and grouping inside instead of using `series`, but I got similar result.

[kendo dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/erUTi/6)

Comment: can you create a codepen or DOJO?

Comment: kendo dojo is at the end of the post

Comment: I see it now. How about this: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/vmyyzN

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your data looks somewhat incorrect, you want your sub categories to repeat. Each category should contain all sub-categories ex:

```
var demoData = [{
Name: 'Category_1',
Total: 100,
Items: [{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_1',
  Total: 50
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_2',
  Total: 45
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_3',
  Total: 5
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_4',
  Total: null
}]
},{
Name: 'Category_2',
Total: 20,
Items: [{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_1',
  Total: 15
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_2',
  Total: 45
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_3',
  Total: null
},{
    Name: 'Sub_Category_4',
  Total: null
}]
},....
```

You also need to group your data by setting up a datasource:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
data: parsedData.seriesArray,
  group: {
    field: "name",
  },
  sort: [
    { field: "stack", dir: "asc" },
    { field: "name", dir: "asc" },
  ]
});
```

Now setup your series and categoryAxis:

```
dataSource: ds,
series: [{
    field: "data",
    stack: true,
}],
categoryAxis: {
  field: "stack",
},
```

And finally, you should not be adding your "data" field to an array in seriesArray:

```
data: data[i].Items[j].Total
```

[dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/oJeHo)